# Making a calculation with only a subset of a data frame

Tags: r, rstudio

I am having a difficulty while doing some statistical analysis for an assignment. I have a df with over 100,000 rows and 15 columns.

My question is, how can I create a calculation that will only use the first 50 or so rows of the df?

So, for example, use only the first 40 rows of this df and calculate the mean of those rows.

Comment: Subsetting dataframes is done by passing a vector (double, integer or logical) to `i` in `df[i,]` e.g. `df[c(1:40),]`

Comment: You could get the means of each row by `apply()` for example `apply(df[1:50, ], 1, mean)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of subsetting. Subsetting can be done via a dataframe's indices. These can be accessed via square brackets: e.g., `df[1, 1]`selects a single value, namely that at the crosssection of the first row and the first column. If you wish to specify only rows, just leave the slot after the comma empty.

**ILLUSTRATIVE DATA**:

Suppose you have this kind of data:

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(rnorm(100, 1)),
  V2 = c(rnorm(100, 2)),
  V3 = c(rnorm(100, 3)),
  V4 = c(rnorm(100, 4)),
  V5 = c(rnorm(100, 5))
)
df
```

**SOLUTION**:

If you want to calculate the means for all columns but only the first 40 rows in the dataframe, just leave the slot after the comma empty, and select the range of rows, and `apply` the function `mean` to this subset of rows column-wise (indicated in the argument `2`):

```
apply(df[1:40,], 2, mean)
```

**RESULT**:

```
       V1        V2        V3        V4        V5 
0.8832314 2.1333252 2.8625274 3.9405622 4.8542093
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subset the dataframe to select required number of rows and then use `rowMeans` to calculate row-wise mean.

```
rowMeans(df[1:40, ])
```